# Access to SQL Server from Flutter Desktop for Windows

Tags: sql-server, flutter

Flutter Desktop for Windows (Alpha version) is out since a few days.
I need to know how to querying SQL Server from Flutter Desktop for Windows?

I have found the package [dart_mssql](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_mssql) but a note says:
"This package is not suitable for flutter or web projects. It only runs on server-side apps."

So do you have an idea how to be querying data from SQL Server in Flutter Desktop for Windows?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The whole appeal of flutter is to service multiple platforms. Accessing your database directly is basically desktop-only, while having a proper backend that calls the database would be a valid architecture for all platforms. If you want to restrict yourself to desktop, there are probably better languages and frameworks than flutter in an alpha state.

Comment: Than k you for your comment. Why would I want to do that ? beacause Flutter desktop is a Windows application, and I need to use it in place of other application types like WinForm in .Net. My need is create a Windows Application that could access to a local database SQL Server.

Comment: There's not a native SQL client solution for Flutter that I'm aware of. Even the [SqlServerSocket](https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket) solution is a client-side component that exchanges JSON messages with a server-side component that actually communicates with an SQL Server. Unlike a lot of modern script languages, though, Flutter can do Socket IO (not just WebSockets) so it's at least possible to implement a [TDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/893fcc7e-8a39-4b3c-815a-773b7b982c50) client on top of Flutter's RawSocket class.